# Mounting a USB external drive question

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I have a Thermaltake hard drive dock that I use to access data on my many hard drives. I have one internal drive that I keep mounted all the time for music, etc but I like to pop drives in and out with my dock. Is there a way to have any drive that is added to the dock mount to the same location every time?

Let's say I have a 3TB drive, 2TB drive and a 1TB drive. When I put the 3TB in the dock, I would like it to mount to `/mnt/winexternal`. Later on in the day, I want to dock my 1TB drive, and I would like it to mount to the same location as the 3TB was previously `/mnt/winexternal` and so on with the 2TB drive.

Is this possible? I am on the most recent version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you need to specify where every partition is mounted  in **fstab**.

### Tutorial

1. Get the **UUID** (Universally Unique Identifier) of every of your hard drives you like to mount in one and the same folder.
   Plug the HDD in and run

   ```
   sudo blkid
   ```

   and copy the UUID of the drive you want to mount. Write it down on a piece of paper or, for less typing, in a text file. Repeat for all three disks.
2. Create the main folder for your mounts.

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/winexternal
   ```
3. Create a symlink for each of your drives.

   ```
   sudo ln -s /mnt/winexternal /mnt/drive1
   sudo ln -s /mnt/winexternal /mnt/drive2
   sudo ln -s /mnt/winexternal /mnt/drive3
   ...
   ```
4. Edit `/etc/fstab` to specify a mount point for each of your drives.
   Add the following lines to the end of the file. (Make sure to create a backup first!).

   ```
   UUID=<UUID_OF_DRIVE_ONE>    /mnt/drive1    ntfs    auto,defaults    0    0
   UUID=<UUID_OF_DRIVE_TWO>    /mnt/drive2    ext4    auto,defaults    0    0
   UUID=<UUID_OF_DRIVE_THREE>    /mnt/drive3    vfat    auto,defaults    0    0
   ```

   Make sure to replace the placeholders `<...>` with the actual UUID of the drive and adjust the filesystem type (`ntfs/ext4/vfat`) to match with the drive.

Now, when you plug in a drive, you should be able to see it's contents in `/mnt/winexternal`. If you then unplug it and plug in the next one, the folder will show it's contents and the same goes for the third drive.

### CAUTION

Unmount the disk before you pull it out. Else, the other drives can't be mounted until a reboot.

Also, make sure that only one drive is connected at a time, else... well, I don't know, but something like your computer bursting into flames or something like that. ;)

No seriously, **DON'T DO IT!** (Probably causes data loss...)

Comment: thanks so much this is great. Also used this information for mounting my internal drives by UUID. I haven't set it up for externals yet but I started building some of the pieces. thanks again for all the help

Comment: You're welcome! If you got it to work, please remember to mark my answer as correct. Thank you!

Comment: I tested this out tonight works great so far but one issue. When I boot up the machine it hangs on the entry that is not plugged in. So I have two 1T Seagate drives, same model but different UUID's. I setup the fstab for both but only using one right now. I rebooted for all my settings to take effect (fstab,samba) and it hangs on the first entry because the drive is not plugged in. I hit S and it continued. Is there a way around this? Or maybe a timeout setting? thanks!!!

Comment: Try adding `retry=1` to the options of each drive. So it should be `auto,defaults,retry=1`. That way, fstab will only try to mount it twice.

Comment: that didn't work, I will post my fstab settings 
UUID=0C40D72340D711F6 /mnt/winexternal ntfs rw,auto,user,fmask=0111,dmask=0000,retry=1
UUID=3EEC0416EC03C6DD /mnt/winexternal ntfs rw,auto,user,fmask=0111,dmask=0000,retry=1

Comment: Oh, I see. You are trying to mount both devices in the same mount point which isn't possible/allowed. Thats why you need to create symlinks (point 3 of my tutorial).

Comment: it's not? seems to work. What would be the issues keeping it the way I have it? Instead of the retry I added nobootwait to both entries. It loaded fine so far but I need to do some testing. thanks

Comment: Ok, if you got it to work like that, that's fine :)

Comment: I found another one, noauto,x-systemd.automount this would mount them at first access instead of boot. I guess I can experiment with both :) thanks for the help at least I have a few things to try out plus your setting up of symlinks